# Some APIs doesn't work In Next js on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a project on Next js. It's working development correctly but when I deploy it some apis doesn't work.

backend api:
https://mutfakci.westhospital.az/api/blog

frontend blog:
https://front.westhospital.az/blog/1

blog page:

```
const Detail = ({ article }) => {
  console.log(article);
  return (
    <section id="blog_detail">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12 p-0">
            <div className="dtail_img">
              <img src="/FORWEB01 1 (1).png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <BlogDetailMain article={article} />
      {/*    <LatesBlog/> */}
      <Coporation />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Detail;

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/blog/${context.params.id}`);

  const responseData = await res.json();

  const article = responseData.data;

  return {
    props: {
      article,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/blog`);

  const articlesResponse = await res.json();
  const articles = articlesResponse.data;

  const ids = articles.map((article) => article.id);
  const paths = ids.map((id) => ({ params: { id: id.toString() } }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

My deploy file:- dep.js:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? 'localhost' : 'front.westhospital.az'
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV || 5522
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Next config file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node dep.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dep.js"
  },
```

I want to render my pages correctly on production.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?